# POST value is not working properly

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have two php files.
one rules.php and one register.php

rules.php is like this:

```
<div style='background-color:#060; color:#FFF; width:50%; height:20px; font-size:12px; margin:5px 0;'>
<form method='post' action='register.php' name='form_coding_rules' id='form_coding_rules'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='rules' id='rules' value='agree'/>
    I Declare That I Read All The Above Rules & I Agree With Them.<br/><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='terms' id='terms' value='Proceed'/>
</form> 
</div>
</center>
```

And the register.php is as follows:

```
if( isset($_POST["terms"]) && isset($_POST["rules"]) && $_POST["rules"]=="agree" ) {
         //Do Something;
}
else
    header("location: rules.php");
```

But the problem is when I'm submitting from the rule page to register page then values not showing and the if part is skipping. After refresh or submitting 2-3 times if statement executing.
But when I'm replacing the action page with a test page which just print the submitted values then everything fine.
Didn't understand why its happening.

Comment: This: `$_POST["rules"]="agree"`, is a declaration, which will evaluate to `true` I believe (I may be thinking of JS). you need two equals signs (or three if you want to check variable type as well).

Comment: And you can always do `var_dump( $_POST ); exit;` at the top if you are confused why one statement might not be what you think.

Comment: can you delete all what is inside your register.php and add print_r($_POST); submit some values and show us result

Comment: any re-writes taking place that could be redirecting and/or trashing the POST and turning it into a GET? e.g. what does `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` and `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: Ok. I changed the action page to a test.php where I just wrote those given 3lines 
& I got this results

Array ( [rules] => agree [terms] => Proceed ) POST

array (size=2)
  'rules' => string 'agree' (length=5)
  'terms' => string 'Proceed' (length=7)

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal Have a look at my answer, unless something changed since.

Comment: I replied. Please give reply for it.

Answer (score 2):

Your last POST in your if statement is:

```
$_POST["rules"]="agree"
```

Should be

```
$_POST["rules"]=="agree"
```

Comment: Also after your header be sure to put an `exit` so it would be else `{ header("location: rules.php"); exit; }`

Comment: The former resolves to `true`, correct? So it wouldn't stop the `if` statement code from running.

Comment: It was a typo here. Sorry. I did this but still not working. I'm confused because when I'm opening it directly by URL then its working. But when I'm going to it by clicking several links it not working. I didn't face this type of problem before.